# The convergence or divergence of two improper integrals

Tags: analysis

I want to investigate the  convergence  or divergence of the  following   improper integrals :

$$(1)\displaystyle\int_{0}^{+\infty} (-1)^{[x^2]}dx;$$
$$(2)\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}|x-a_k|^{p_k}},$$
where $a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_n.$

I have no idea about them. I would appreciate it if someone can give some suggestions and comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first integral we can use the substitution $u = x^2$

$$\int_0^\infty (-1)^{[x^2]}dx =\int_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^{[u]}}{2\sqrt{u}}du$$

$$= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_n^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^n}{2\sqrt{u}}du = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$

which converges by alternating series test. The second integral requires

$$p_k < 1 \hspace{20 pt} 1\leq k \leq n$$ and $$\sum_{k=1}^n p_k > 1$$

by p-test.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Thanks a lot.